# I am a beginner, How to get cell value in variable in VBA excel?

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to compare cell values in a column in excel. If the number changes from 8 to 7 i have to insert a blank row. So i tried to take the values in variables and then compare them. But i am not able to set the value in variable :(

Comment: I am not able to pick the cell value from the excelsheet which is an output of sql server query. I have to compare 2 cell values and if there is difference then insert  an empty row.  I have just began and stuck . Sorry!

Comment: @amie please post your code or a picture so you can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have the variable on the left and the assignment value on the right, accessed via `.Value` property of `Range` object.

Comparing them depends on what type of comparison you want to do. I show an equal comparison of the two variables. You decide which operator you want to use and place between the two variables.

I am showing single cell comparisons. If you try this with more than one cell you will actually generate an array which can't be housed in an `Integer` variable type. Also, you want `Long` rather than `Integer` to lessen chance of overflow by trying to put too large a numeric value in an `Integer`. You are also assuming that the datatype in the cell is numeric or can be coerced to numeric.

e.g.

```
currValue = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
compareValue = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value

Debug.Print currValue = compareValue
```

You will need to follow some tutorials to get to understand this as it is pretty fundamental stuff.

Answer (score 1):

A brief explanation how to compare:

```
Sub Compare()

Dim CellValue As Integer, CompareWithValue As Integer

CellValue = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value '<= The value in the A1 of Sheet1
CompareWithValue = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value '<= The value in the A2 of 
                    Sheet1

If CellValue > CompareWithValue Then '<= Compare if CellValue is greater than 
CompareWithValue (here you can also use < or =)
'what do you want to happen if the above condition is true
End If

End Sub
```